# A 2x4 in a doorway

Tags: geometry

This problem has puzzled me for years.  I've asked students, teachers and engineers and none of them have solved it.  It looks simple, but as of yet, no solution.  I can come up with several equations, but I can't reduce them down to a solution.

Imagine a doorway of height "A" and width "B".  You have a board of width "w".  You want to place the board in the door frame and run it corner to corner.  The board must just fit (too long and it won't fit inside the door way, too short and it doesn't run corner to corner).  I'm looking for the general solution so that it could be used for any door size and a board of any width.  You can introduce any number of angles to solve this, but your final solution must be purely in terms of "A", "B", and "w".

I would love to see a worked solution (or a layman's explanation as to why there isn't one).

Have fun!

I had a diagram drawn, but I'm too new to this site so it couldn't be posted

Comment: I can't make sense of what you want. Do you want to know the possible lengths of a board with width $w$, such that all 4 corners of the board will be touching the a different side of the doorway?

Comment: Can you simply use the Pythagorus theorem?

Comment: I think it's a fixed width $w$, and a fixed doorframe, and the question is to solve for the length of the board that *just* fits in the plane of the door (i.e. touching the frame at all four corners). Pythagorean theorem and congruent triangles, with some messy algebra, are enough. Kind of bothers me that math teachers and engineers couldn't solve it.

Comment: @Calvin Lin: I think he means given that the board (running as one diagonal) has a width $w$ which forms the hypothenuse of a triangle in the lower left and upper right corner (say), how much does this reduce the hypotenuse of the trance firmed by $a, b$ and the diagonal, if $w$ were $0$. I upvoted your comment though, not very clear. :)

Comment: ...triangle formed by $a, b$... (typo, which my phone doesn't let me correct, sorry)

Comment: I know, the issue is that with a given (non-zero) width, there are numerous possible lengths depending on the angle that you're tilting the board at.

Comment: @CalvinLin:  Given the width of the board $w$, there is only one length that fits exactly.  The question is what is that length.

Comment: @RossMillikan If the board is rectangular, then yes. However, he said that you can introduce any number of angles, so I was wondering if the board could be a parallelogram. I was referring to the 'tilt' of the board, not the angle against the floor ($t$ in your solution)

Comment: Upload the image to http://imgur.com and post a link here, and someone will add it to the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you let $t$ be the angle created by the door in degrees, the diagram below shows the start.  There are lots of $90-t-(90-t)$ triangles about.  Now you have $B-w\sin t=L \cos t, A-w \cos t = L \sin t, \sin^2t+\cos^2 t=1$, two equations in $\sin t, L$.
The practical answer is to say $w \ll A,B$, in which case you can take $\tan t=\frac AB$ You can't cut accurately enough to care about the corrections.    Then $\sin t=\frac {\frac AB} {\sqrt{1+(\frac AB )^2}}$ $\cos t= \frac 1 {\sqrt{1+(\frac AB )^2}}$  Now divide the equations to get $L \tan t$ and you are there.

[image]

Comment: Your diagram is exactly what I'm describing.

Comment: hmmmm. I get the quantity you call $w \sin t$ as the root of a degree four polynomial. Oh, you are approximating.

Comment: @WillJagy:  That's why I proposed the approximation.  It makes things easy and the error will be small.  You are right that you can solve it exactly, or numerically, but this is the practical approach.  A hammer will solve any error easily.

Answer (score 2):

Using Ross's symbols, I wrote 
$$  x = w \sin t, \; \; y = w \cos t.   $$
Now, there is a solution in radicals for $x,$ but it is very unpleasant because we arrive at
$$ 4 x^4  - 4 B x^3 + (A^2 + B^2 - 4 w^2) x^2 + 2 B w^2 x + (w^2 - A^2) w^2 = 0.   $$
Oh, note
$$  x^2 + y^2 = w^2  $$ and
$$  L^2 = (A-y)^2 + (B-x)^2 = A^2 + B^2 + w^2 - 2 A y - 2 B x.  $$

So, while there is a method for writing the value of $x$ using radicals, see [QUARTIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation), it is just not going to do you any good. I would solve for $x$ numerically, then find $y$ from $y = \sqrt{w^2 - x^2},$ then find $L.$